# Determine which Checkboxes in a Listview are Checked

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a listview with checkbox in each row. I want to create a new listview when i click in a button with only the cheked items, but I don't know how to know which items are selected.

Sorry but i don't get to put my row.xml code...

Answer (score 1):

There are few methods available to get the IDs or positions of the checked items:

> `getCheckedItemPosition ()` - returns
>   an `int` with the currently checked
>   item (only good for
>   `SINGLE_CHOICE_MODE`)

> `getCheckedItemPositions ()` - returns
>   an `int []` with the currently checked
>   items positions

> `getCheckedItemIds ()`
>   - returns a `long []` containing the IDs of the checked items

Comment: But I don't know how to apply this...any code examlpe please?